# Stored procedure return always NULL value on an output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch the value of a stored procedure parameter but it return always a NULL value.

If I execute the stored procedure by the server client it shows the correct value for that parameter, but as you can see from the image, the code returns a null value for the parameter `@esitoRecuperoAmicizie`.

In this screenshot, the debug parameter value:

[image]

This is the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SocialPartyFinder_RecuperaListaAmici_GET] 
    @IdUtente INT,
    @esitoRecuperoAmicizie INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 
            ListaAmici.FkUPropAmicizia, Utenti.Utnte_Username, 
            Utenti.StatoConnessione, Utenti.ImmagineProfilo
        FROM 
            ListaAmici 
        INNER JOIN 
            Utenti ON ListaAmici.FkAmico = Utenti.IdUtente
        WHERE 
            ListaAmici.FkUPropAmicizia = @IdUtente

        SET @esitoRecuperoAmicizie = 10;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @esitoRecuperoAmicizie = 99;
    END CATCH
END
```

This is the code that calls the stored procedures and fetches the value from the parameter:

```
    public List<Utenti> recuperaListaAmici(int id) 
    {
        string errore = String.Empty;
        List<Utenti> listaAmici = new List<Utenti>();

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SocialPartyFinder_RecuperaListaAmici_GET";
        
        SqlParameter parametroInput = new SqlParameter();
        parametroInput.ParameterName = "@IdUtente";
        parametroInput.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametroInput.Value = id;
        parametroInput.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parametroInput);

        SqlParameter parameteroOutput = new SqlParameter();
        parameteroOutput.ParameterName = "@esitoRecuperoAmicizie";
        parameteroOutput.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
        parameteroOutput.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameteroOutput);

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@esitoRecuperoAmicizie"].Value);

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    // DO SOMETHING
                }

                return listaAmici;
            }
            catch
            {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }

        return listaAmici;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the TRY/CATCH in the stored procedure and handle exceptions properly.

Comment: You are checking the output variable to early, check it after the reader has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of Try and Catch should only be for errors,
This query returns two results that will cause an error in the program code, so I suggest you modify the code as follows:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ListaAmici WHERE ListaAmici.FkUPropAmicizia = @IdUtente)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @esitoRecuperoAmicizie = 10
    END
ELSE    
    BEGIN
        SELECT @esitoRecuperoAmicizie = 99
    END

SELECT 
    ListaAmici.FkUPropAmicizia, 
    Utenti.Utnte_Username, 
    Utenti.StatoConnessione, 
    Utenti.ImmagineProfilo, 
    @esitoRecuperoAmicizie AS esitoReroAmicizie
FROM 
    ListaAmici 
    INNER JOIN 
    Utenti ON ListaAmici.FkAmico = Utenti.IdUtente
WHERE 
    ListaAmici.FkUPropAmicizia = @IdUtente
```

Answer (score -1):

The value will be null when you hit the stored procedure because the code logic of `@esitoRecuperoAmicizie` is just being assigned and not added in any value.

Like select `@esitoRecuperoAmicizie` from dual - if you do this this will give you the value returned or set using `@esitoRecuperoAmicizie` variable

Try it .. it will work